# About stronger version of Goldbach conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, goldbachs-conjecture

I was recently looking at a elementary number theory book and there was a conjecture which amazed me. That conjecture is nothing but  Goldbach's conjecture which
says that

> Every even number greater than $3$ can be expressed as sum of two primes.

Even though it is very simpler to understand, it is very difficult to decipher it.

Here is a stronger version of this guessed by me with the aid of limited computational power,

> For every number $n$ greater than $3$ there exist a $k>0$ such that $n-k$ and $n+k$ are prime numbers.

Obviously this is stronger than Goldbach's conjecture since $2n = n - k + n + k$

We define a function $\psi(n)$ which counts number of such pairs for a given number $n$.
Our conjecture is equivalent to saying that $\psi(n)$ is atleast $1$ for $n > 3$. But using computational softwares much more can be conjectured about $\psi(n)$.  I attached a plot of $\psi(n)$ till $n=5000$ [image: Here]

Another way of expressing this is : For each $n>3$,there are infinitely many semi-primes whose prime factors' average is $n$.

It always seems like $\psi(n)$ is bounded below by some positive nonzero function. If we are to approximate this function by a continous function , that function should be highly fluctuating back and forth. For example if we consider vertical strip with narrow width in the graph, it will contain value of $\psi(n)$ and another value $\psi(n)$ which is almost double or triple than former value.

I know that making conjecture without any theoretical basis is not very reasonable even though it provides us a goal to look up and achieve something.

I just wanted know your reactions and insights about this.

Comment: Indeed, you have rediscovered the emperical evidence that supports the Hardy/Littlewood conjecture about the number of such representations. See the bottom of [this section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture#Heuristic_justification) (I believe your $n$ would be $2n$ in their notation).

Comment: This is the same as Goldbach.  If $2n=p+q$ with $p≥q$ then, writing $p=n+k$, we see that $q=n-k$.

Comment: This version is "stronger" only in that by requiring $k>0$ it dismisses the instances where $2n=2p$

Comment: As observed by lulu, your conjecture is exactly the Goldbach conjecture. The only “difference” is that for every $k$ such that $2n=n-k+n+k$ and $n+k,n-k$ are both prime numbers then you have a different representation for every $k$. You could obtain something “stronger” if you assume some conditions on $k$, like “if $n$ is sufficiently large there exists two positive integers $k_{1},\, k_{2}\leq n$ such that $n+k_{1},\,n-k_{1},\,n+k_{2},\,n-k_{2}$ are primes” (an note we think it is true since the conjectured number of representations grows, as $n \rightarrow + \infty$, like $n/\log^{2}(n)$).